# Add user info to profile with Devise authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a Devise authentication set up correctly and i'm trying to add a user profile page (currently using `users#show`).

I want the user to be able to information like address(es).

Do i have to create a model for that as i want the user to do CRUD with it?

Here is what i have by now:
`show.html.erb`

```
<%= content_for :title, "#{current_user.prenom} #{current_user.nom} - profil" %>

<%= render partial: 'layouts/jsnav' %>

<%= render partial: 'users/header' %>

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'infos')">Mes informations</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'adresses')">Mes adresses</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'commandes')">Mes commandes</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'avis')">Mes avis</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'fidelite')">Espace fidélité</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'parrainage')">Parrainage</button>
</div>

<div id="infos" class="tabcontent">
  <%= render partial: 'users/informations' %>
</div>

<div id="adresses" class="tabcontent">
  <%= render partial: 'users/adresses' %>
</div>

<div id="commandes" class="tabcontent">
  <%= render partial: 'users/commandes' %>
</div>

<div id="avis" class="tabcontent">
  <%= render partial: 'users/avis' %>
</div>

<div id="fidelite" class="tabcontent">
  <%= render partial: 'users/fidelite' %>
</div>

<div id="parrainage" class="tabcontent">
  <%= render partial: 'users/parrainage' %>
</div>
```

`users_controller.rb` :

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  include Devise::Controllers::Helpers
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user_adresse = current_user.adresse
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.assign_attributes(user_params)

    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = "Votre profil a été modifié"
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Une erreur est survenue lors de la modification de votre profil"
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit!
  end

end
```

Here is the content of the partials `users/adresses` :

```
<section id="user-add-adresse-container">
  <% if @current_user.adresse %>
    <%= current_user.adresse %>
  <% end %>

  <%= form_for @user, url: edit_user_path(@user), method: :get do |f| %>
    <div class="field" id="adresse-field">
      <%= f.label :adresse %>
      <%= f.text_field :adresse, placeholder: 'Saisissez votre adresse' %>
    </div>
    <div class="field" id="adresse-field">
      <%= f.label :code_postal %>
      <%= f.text_field :code_postal, placeholder: 'Saisissez votre code postal' %>
    </div>
    <div class="field" id="adresse-field">
      <%= f.label :ville %>
      <%= f.text_field :ville, placeholder: 'Saisissez votre ville' %>
    </div>
    <div class="field" id="adresse-field">
      <%= f.label :pays %>
      <%= f.select :pays, User::CHOIX_PAYS, placeholder: 'Sélectionnez votre pays' %>
    </div>
    <div class="submit" id="user-add-adresse-submit">
      <%= f.submit "Ajouter l'adresse" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</section>
```

This doesn't work. There's something i miss here.

Comment: Can you share the contents of users/adresses partial? It looks like you missed to use the variables you mentioned in the controller

Comment: And...what is not working? what are your errors???

Comment: @NaveenValluri I just edited the question.

Comment: @SebastiánMeza I can't edit it. I just don't know how to do it. I don't have any error message

Comment: Why are you using **@current_user** variable and **@user** if you have _current_user_ ? 

I think your problem is in show action, if you can trace and see what comes in params[:id] maybe this search is unnecesary if you want to edit the same data from current_user

Comment: @SebastiánMeza i want the user to be able to add one or several addresses and find them both in the user profile and during the payment process for delivery